# JLayeredPane with a LayoutManager

Tags: java, swing, constraints, layout-manager, jlayeredpane

The situation: drawing a stack of playing cards, like in the Solitaire game. Nicely stacked.

To achieve this, I'm using a `JLayeredPane` in combination with a custom implementation of the `LayoutManager` interface. The reason for using a custom LayoutManager is that the stack orientation varies, sometimes the playing cards cover each other completely, sometimes partially, and this logic seems to be a good job for a LayoutManager, because this basically boils down to setting the location of the cards.

So, the `LayoutManager` is responsible for setting the X- and Y-coordinates of all components in my stack. The `JLayeredPane` on the other hand is responsible for their Z-coordinates (via its layers).

Adding a component to a `JLayeredPane` goes like this:

```
JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();
pane.setLayout(new StackLayout(...));
pane.add(new CardView(...), new Integer(j));
```

where `new Integer(j)` is the layer of the card. This must be an `Integer` due to the contract of `JLayeredPane`.

The problem here is, that my `StackLayout` cannot have any other constraint object than an `Integer`, due to the reason stated above. The `LayoutManager` interface requires you to implement the following method:

```
addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints);
```

and the passed `Object` will here always be an `Integer`.

In my particular situation, I am lucky, as my XY-coordinates can be calculated based on the Z-coordinates. For example, the card in layer `k` has to be located at Y-coordinate `k * offset`. So in my situation, the constraints object being an `Integer` is not a problem.

I was wondering what you should be doing when there is no correlation between the Z-coordinates and the XY-coordinates? How can you solve this then? For example, how would I use a `GridBagLayout` in combination with a `JLayeredPane`, where the first requires a `GridBagConstraints` object and the second an `Integer` object? Of course, a GBL will layout in such a way that components do not overlap, but it's just the idea.

Comment: Have you thought about extending JLayeredPane since you are needing to alter a basic behavior? This way you could create your own add method that would allow for its own specific Object 2nd parameter, one that combined the Integer required of the JLayeredPane super, and perhaps the GridBagConstraints if the layout used GridBagLayout or something similar.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It seems that might be the proper solution. I think I might need to override `protected void addImpl(Component comp, Object constraints, int index)` which `JLayeredPane` overrides itself, to intercept the `Integer` object first which is used for layer determination. Then it passes on the constraints to its super class, `Container`, which ultimately won't do anything with it as a default `JLayeredPane` has no LayoutManager. I will write an answer for this approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comment of Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I'll answer my own question.

Calling `JLayeredPane.add(Component comp, Object constraints)` will call `addImpl(Component comp, Object constraints, int index)`. This method is overridden by JLayeredPane itself, here's the source:

```
protected void addImpl(Component comp, Object constraints, int index) {
    int layer;
    int pos;

    if(constraints instanceof Integer) {
        layer = ((Integer)constraints).intValue();
        setLayer(comp, layer);
    } else
        layer = getLayer(comp);

    pos = insertIndexForLayer(layer, index);
    super.addImpl(comp, constraints, pos);
    comp.validate();
    comp.repaint();
    validateOptimizedDrawing();
}
```

As you can see, the `Integer` object is intercepted, so that the JLayeredPane knows the layer in which `comp` should be placed. Then, it passes on `constraints`, the Integer, to the super implementation. The essential part in the super implementation, `Container`, is:

```
protected void addImpl(Component comp, Object constraints, int index) {
    ...
    if (layoutMgr != null) {
        if (layoutMgr instanceof LayoutManager2) {
           ((LayoutManager2)layoutMgr).addLayoutComponent(comp, constraints);
        } else if (constraints instanceof String) {
           layoutMgr.addLayoutComponent((String)constraints, comp);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The solution would therefore be to extend `JLayeredPane` and override its `addImpl(Component comp, Object constraints, int index)` method, which can accept any Object of your choice: this object should contain the `Integer` needed for the JLayeredPane's layer decision, and it should also contain the constraints object for the chosen LayoutManager.

StackConstraints:

```
public final class StackConstraints {
    public final int layer;
    public final Object layoutConstraints;
    public StackConstraints (int layer, Object layoutConstraints){
        this.layer = layer;
        this.layoutConstraints = layoutConstraints;
    }
}
```

JLayeredPane extension:

```
protected void addImpl(Component comp, Object constraints, int index) {
    int layer;
    int pos;
    Object constr;
     if(constraints instanceof StackConstraints) {
        layer = constraints.layer.intValue();
        constr = ((StackConstraints) constraints).layoutConstraints;
        setLayer(comp, layer);
    } else {
        layer = getLayer(comp);
        constr = constraints;
    }

    pos = insertIndexForLayer(layer, index);
    super.addImpl(comp, constraints, pos);
    comp.validate();
    comp.repaint();
    validateOptimizedDrawing();
```

}

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion (it's helped me a lot) but the code wouldn't work as it is.
1) layer = constraints.layer.intValue() should be changed to ((StackConstraints) constraints).layer.
2) if constr happen to be of type Integer, super.addImpl(...) would reset the layering.
3) validateOptimizedDrawing() is a private method of JLayeredPane. You cannot call it from subclasses.

Comment: Here's an alternative:

`protected void addImpl(Component comp, Object constraints, int index) {
  int layer = 0;
  int pos = 0;

  Object constr;
  if (constraints instanceof StackConstraints) {
   layer = ((StackConstraints) constraints).layer;
   constr = ((StackConstraints) constraints).layoutConstraints;
  } else {
   layer = getLayer(comp);
   constr = constraints;
  }

  pos = insertIndexForLayer(layer, index);
  super.addImpl(comp, constr, pos);

  setLayer(comp, layer, pos);

  comp.validate();
  comp.repaint();
 }`

Answer (score 3):

> So, the LayoutManager is responsible for setting the X- and Y-coordinates of all components in my stack. The JLayeredPane on the other hand is responsible for their Z-coordinates (via its layers).

You don't need to use a layered pane for this. A panel also supports Z-Order. Check out the [Overlap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) which explains more about this and may do what you need.

Comment: While your LM will do for most games, my layout is entirely vectorial/relatively defined. Therefore, I don't calculate parent sizes based on preferred children sizes, but the other way around. A LM using preferred/minimum/maximum sizes of the child components would therefore not be the best choice, at least not in my case. I appreciate your answer though, I will investigate if I can use it in my project. But the question was about the combination of JLayeredPane with a LayoutManager, not about alternatives. Any reason why you wouldn't use JLayeredPane's built-in layering?

Comment: @Timmos, `the question was about the combination of JLayeredPane with a LayoutManager, not about alternatives.` - I gave an alternative because you may not have thought about that approach and it may give you new ideas. `Any reason why you wouldn't use JLayeredPane's built-in layering?` - Your solution involves overriding JLayeredPane and creating a custom layout manager. My suggestion keeps the code in just the layout manager which I think is cleaner. Maybe you can combine your Vectorial layout approach with my ZOrder approach?